# What does the Frechet derivative tell us about fixed points of a functional relationship?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm aware that the Frechet derivative of an operator is a generalization of derivatives for the purposes of function and operator spaces, but I still don't have the best idea of what it's actually doing.

In another question, I asked about analyzing the equation $x = (f(x) + a)(f(x)+b)$ for invertible $f$ and asked if there's insights into analytically approximating or explicitly calculating the solution using fixed point theorems.

Well, what is the Frechet derivative of $(f(x) + a)(f(x)+b)$ and what does that Frechet derivative tell us about this functional relationship and fixed points, if anything at all?

Comment: What is $f$? Is $f : X \to X$ with $X$ Banach?

Comment: We have (by the fundamental theorem of calculus or otherwise) that $\|g(y) - g(x)\| \leq \sup_{t \in [0, 1]}\|Dg(x + t(y - x))\|\|y - x\|$. So if $\sup_{y}\|Dg(y)\| < 1$, then $g$ is a contraction and by the contraction mapping theorem, $g$ has a unique fixed point. Also Netwon's method can work, under more assumptions.

Comment: @Ning Yes......

Comment: @Mason that's interesting but I'm a little confused by the brevity. Would you mind demonstrating this on a function in one variable, like how it might hold true or false for $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: @StackQuest The inverse function theorem uses the method of proof I stated above to show that if $X$ is a Banach space and $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X$ and $F : U \to X$ is $C^k$ and $DF(0)$ is invertible, then there is a neighborhood $O \subset U$ of $0$ such that $F : O \to F(O)$ is a $C^k$ with $C^k$ inverse. In your case, we have $f'(x) = 2x \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$. Using the inverse function theorem, we can easily show that $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is $C^\infty$ on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: What is the significance of $g(x)$? Because I was taking $f(x)$ to be a general invertible function, like let's say $f(x)$ could be $x^2,$ or $e^x$ or $sin(x)$ over a sufficiently small domain.